# Python - Extracting Text from a <td class = "text">Need This Text</td>

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am new to selenium and python, so my overall goal is to extract the revenue value for a company from the website Hoovers.

Current code:

```
company = 'Trelleborg'
page = 'https://hoovers.com/company-information/cs.html?term=' + company
driver.get(page)

r = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td/font[@class="company_sales"]').text
print(r)
```

HTML for the Desired Revenue

```
<td class="company_name">
  <a href="/company-information/cs/company- 
  profile.trelleborg_ab.a545a8005aced58d.html">
  Trelleborg AB</a>
</td>
<td class="company_location">Trelleborg, Skåne, Sweden</td>
<td class="company_sales">$3842.84M</td>
```

I would like to extract the **$3842.84M** text into a variable. I have tried many different solutions that I have found online but keep on receiving the NoSuchElementException error message.  Any Help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: You're looking for `//td[@class="company_sales"]`, there's no `font` element in your snippet

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name("company_sales").text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract and print the text **$3842.84M** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *visibility of element located* and you can use the following solution:

- Code BlocK:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  company = 'Trelleborg'
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  page = 'https://hoovers.com/company-information/cs.html?term=' + company
  driver.get(page)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cmp-company-directory']//tbody//td/a[contains(., '"+company +"')]//following::td[2]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  $3842.84M
  ```

Comment: How did you acquire the XPATH?

Comment: @KenPen I havn't acquired the xpath from anywhere but constructed it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In this case You can find element by class name or CSS Sector or XPath.

If you want to use XPath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="company_sales"]').text
```

OR if you want to use CSS Sector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td.company_sales").text
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".company_sales").text
```

OR if you want use class name:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("company_sales").text
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I tried each of these solutions and an error is outputted:  No such element: unable to locate element.

Comment: It should work.I have tested this code in chrome browser and it works perfectly.If you want i can share you the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like issue with XPath. Generally Xpath format is like.

```
Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']
```

- // : Select current node.
- Tagname: Tagname of the particular node.
- @:    Select attribute.
- Attribute: Attribute name of the node.
- Value: Value of the attribute.

So, Resultant xpath in your case must looks like.

```
//td[@class="company_sales"]
```